# ignore continuously changing file locally in git

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm working on a web app project that uses Jenkins to build to a development, release candidate, and production server. Each server has a Jenkins job task that runs and increments the build number to the latest version number: version.json

The file is required to be part of the git project, so the Jenkins release candidate job commits and pushes to the remote, which gets built by production 1:1 from the rc branch. Locally, though, it's getting rewritten in every branch (from RC version back to develop version) and is regretfully part of every commit file change that gets pushed to remote for a pull request.

How can I require a file to be included in all but local working copies? Or to have changes to the local file ignored?

Comment: Have a look at sparse checkout,you can have git omit and then utterly disregard that file in all further checkouts.

Comment: Have you consider making your local files as unchanged with `git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file`?